# how to align tabsetpanel "pills" center in R shiny

Tags: css, r, shiny

I am trying to center-align tabsetpanel "pills" on shiny, but it alwais get on left position. Here is the code example, anyone knows how to align this buttons or pills center?

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  tabPanel(title = "Hello world", value = "HB", 
           tabsetPanel(id="subtabs", type="pills", 
                       tabPanel(title = "TAB 1", value = "ILPF", 
                                br(),
                                h4("I like Pink floyd, my favourite album is 'The dark side of the moon'", style = "color:grey", align = "center"),
                                br()
                       ),
                       tabPanel(title = "TAB 2", value = "FS",  
                                br(),
                                h4("But my favourite song is 'Shine on you crazy diamond'", style = "color:grey", align = "center"),
                                br()
                                )
                       )
           )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[The pills should be in the middle of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tM7Qo.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so by adding some CSS to your app. `tags$style('ul.nav-pills{display: flex !important;justify-content: center !important;}')` does the trick.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style('
    ul.nav-pills{
      display: flex !important;
      justify-content: center !important;
    }')
  ),
  tabPanel(title = "Hello world", value = "HB", 
           tabsetPanel(id="subtabs", type="pills", 
                       tabPanel(title = "TAB 1", value = "ILPF", 
                                br(),
                                h4("I like Pink floyd, my favourite album is 'The dark side of the moon'", style = "color:grey", align = "center"),
                                br()
                       ),
                       tabPanel(title = "TAB 2", value = "FS",  
                                br(),
                                h4("But my favourite song is 'Shine on you crazy diamond'", style = "color:grey", align = "center"),
                                br()
                       )
           )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]